# Pyglet: how to handle heavy resources loading

Tags: pyglet

I'm learning pyglet in order to write a game, and I've trying to create a loading screen/scene while loading all game resources (static images and image sprites), to avoid window freeze while loading. I wonder what are the best practices to handle heavy resources loading with pyglet, on window/game startup or between scenes.